# Could a JVM possibly optimize the memory required for references to null, the instance of null type?

Tags: java, memory, jvm-hotspot

Good afternoon all,

I have a class which looks like this:

```
public class Grapheme {
    public Grapheme(int[] code_points) {
        this.code_points = code_points;
    }
    int[] code_points;
}
```

From the [link](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml) provided by bdonlan [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9060244/632951), I understand that typically a Grapheme object would require 8 bytes for object header, 4 bytes for the variable `code_points` (whose type is *reference*), and 4 bytes of padding.

So if I create an instance of Grapheme using the code `new Grapheme(null)`, that instance of Grapheme would typically require a total of 16 bytes. Since whether or not it is 16 bytes is implementation specific, from here on I'll refer to *this number* as *x* bytes.

Basically I was wondering if I create *n* number of Graphemes, passing `null` into the constructor `Grapheme(int[])` for all of them, and store those Graphemes into an array of length *n*,

Will the total memory required by the runtime (to store the Grapheme instances) be **strictly** *n* * *x* bytes?

Or is there **any chance** that the JVM could try and do some magic optimizations such that the memory required is below *n* * *x* bytes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The size of an object is fixed. Consider - if the JVM did pack your Graphemes into an array with no space between them, what happens if some code changes the value of `code_points` later? It'd have to move all the other Graphemes around, and rewrite any pointers to any of them. This would be a HUGE performance hit (you'd probably need to perform a full GC to rewrite all those pointers...), and be totally inscrutable to the programmer trying to figure out why a simple assignment was so slow. So the JVM does no optimizations of this sort.

Also note that your overhead estimates are a bit off. According to [this page](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml), objects have an overhead of 8 bytes, plus the space for any internal fields, for 12 bytes. This is then rounded up to a multiple of 8 bytes - so your Grapheme object here would be 16 bytes in total on a 32-bit platform and the Hotspot JVM. Any pointers to the Grapheme object will take additional space (probably 4 bytes each). Objects do not need space for their own address per se; that memory is owned by something else (eg, a stack frame, or another object).

Comment: Btw what do you mean by "space for any internal fields" ? According to the page you've linked, isn't it true that it's a total of 8 (housekeeping) + 4 (reference of null)) = 12 bytes = 16 bytes after rounding to nearest 8 = 16 bytes per Grapheme object (yes we get the same result but the working is different)?

Comment: Internal fields = `int[] code_points`. So our math is the same :)